# why java.sql.Timestamp return negative value when the date is after 1970-01-01

Tags: java, timestamp, sql-timestamp

```
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("1970-01-01 01:00:00");
System.out.println(timestamp.getTime());
```

Any idea this code returns -25200000 ?
I thought time after 1970-01-01 00:00:00 will be positive.

Comment: `I thought time after 1970-01-01 00:00:00 will be positive` <- Everything after 1970-1-1 00:00:00 **GMT** will be positive. Since you are parsing a DateTime without any Zone information the result you get will depend on the timezone of the computer you are running it on. (As it will interpret the Date/Time to refer to the current Zone of the System)

Comment: I see, it seems that I cannot add a Z in the string like this: "1970-01-01 01:00:00 Z" it will throw exception. Any idea? @OHGODSPIDERS

Answer (score 1):

You are using a terrible date-time class that was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Parse your input as a `LocalDateTime` because it lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Replace the SPACE in middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601 standard for date-time formats.

```
String input = "1970-01-01 01:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Apparently you mean for that to represent a moment in UTC. Apply an offset to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Get a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
long millis = odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

> 3600000

Comment: Thanks. The reason using that is because hive is using that to represent timestamp, and jdbc uses it

Comment: @Bargitta As of JDBC 4.2, we can use *java.time* objects instead of `java.sql.Timestamp`. Specifically `OffsetDateTime`, and optionally `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`. You can convert back and forth from `Timestamp` by calling new conversion methods added to that old class.